# Unity3d Create AnimationCurve from code (issue)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I am trying to create ui animation from code. Position animation works fine, but rotation curves created wrong.

[image]
[image]

rotation value changing only in last frame. why?

```
var angle = Quaternion.Euler(FadeOutEndAngleX, FadeOutEndAngleY, FadeOutEndAngleZ);

curve1 = AnimationCurve.Linear(0f, 0f, 0.5f, Screen.width);
curve2 = AnimationCurve.Linear(0f, 0f, 0.5f, Screen.height);
curve3 = AnimationCurve.Linear(0f, 0f, 0.5f, angle.x);
curve4 = AnimationCurve.Linear(0f, 0f, 0.5f, angle.y);
curve5 = AnimationCurve.Linear(0f, 0f, 0.5f, angle.z);
curve6 = AnimationCurve.Linear(0f, 0f, 0.5f, angle.w);

clip.SetCurve("", typeof(RectTransform), "m_AnchoredPosition.x", curve1);
clip.SetCurve("", typeof(RectTransform), "m_AnchoredPosition.y", curve2);
clip.SetCurve("", typeof(RectTransform), "localRotation.x", curve3);
clip.SetCurve("", typeof(RectTransform), "localRotation.y", curve4);
clip.SetCurve("", typeof(RectTransform), "localRotation.z", curve5);
clip.SetCurve("", typeof(RectTransform), "localRotation.w", curve6);
```